# Getting "variable is undefined return Proxy" in a Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to check if a value is taken, and if it is then im skipping to the next value . This is done by a simple recursion

```
function recur(id){
    if($('#'+id).length != 0){ // checking if id exists on page
       recur(id++);
    }
    else{
        return id;
    }
}

$.(document).ready(function(){
     var x = recur(1);
     alert(x);
});
```

But I get this error:

```
x is undefined
 return proxy
```

Comment: Why do you use recursion to iterate over an array? Use `for`

Comment: I am actually checking if jQuery(#+'id').length !=0 ( ie on the page, that id exists). So go to next 1 . Wanted to make it simple for people to understand

Comment: Downvoted. Fix your syntax errors/typos. Clarify question. Output of your code does not match what you stated.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a return statement for the recursive call:

```
function recur (id){
  if($('#'+id).length != 0){ 
      return recur(id++); // add return here
  }
  else{
      return id;
}
```

Without it, only the terminating case will return a value, but it won't get passed up the stack. So the top-most `recur` call does actually return `undefined`.

I personally would not use recursion but rather do it iteratively:

```
function nextId(id) {
    while ($('#'+id).length != 0) {
        ++id;
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY GOD ! THANKS . HAVE BEEN RATTLING MY BRAINS OUT 1!